# Saving Multiple records in hibernate using for loop

Tags: java, hibernate

I am saving multiple objects of an entity into the database,using hibernate.
I want that if an exception occurs in one record, then it should be caught and code should not break i.e other records should persist.

For example,\

While saving multiple records , there is a record, whose size one the field values, is larger than the size of the database column size. So value too large to be inserted in the column, exception is thrown while persisting this record. Ideally, this exception should be caught and it should not restrict rest of the records in the loop from getting persisted. But in actual scenario, it breaks the code and records after this faulty record, do not get inserted into the database i.e exception is thrown and loop breaks. below is the code snippet that is running to achive this

```
@Override
public void persistActivityLog(List<ActivityLog> acLogList) {
    List<ActivityLog> failedActivityTasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ActivityLog activityLog : acLogList) {
        try {
            Long runid = activityDAO.persistActivityLogData(activityLog);
        } catch (DataException exp) {
            failedTasks.add(activityLog);
        }
    }
}

@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public Long persistActivityLogData(ActivityLog activityLog) throws DataAccessException {
    Session session = null;
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(activityLog);
    return activityLog.getActivityLogId();
}
```

In the above code, when sql exception is thrown it is not caught inside the for loop catch block, rather exception breaks the code, when a faulty record tries to get inserted.
Is there a way, so that faulty records get skipped, the code enters into the catch block and other records gets persisted successfully. EArlier I was using Transactional annotation on the persistActivityLog method , but later on I changed this to be applied on persistActivityLogData method , so that records get inserted one by one, and not in batch. But even after that I am getting this exception.

Comment: have you tried sending the list and do the save loop inside the transactional method? just s thought..

Comment: Only unchecked exceptions (that is, subclasses of java.lang.RuntimeException) are rollbacked by default. For the case, a checked exception is thrown, the transaction will be committed!

Comment: @Angad— that is fine but how can i catch the exception in the loop.

Comment: Try saving entity inside for loop .Try-catch also inside for-loop and commit.tx outside the for-loop.Do not do any stuff in catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It might be work.

```
    @Override
public void persistActivityLog(List<ActivityLog> acLogList) {
    Session session = null;
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    for (ActivityLog activityLog : acLogList) {
        try {
           session.save(activityLog);
        } catch (NonUniqueObjectException e) {
            //dont do anything here
        }
    }
    tx.commit();

}
```